# Europe map with mean values ​in the middle of each country

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, plotly

I create a map of Europe with `ggplot()`. In addition, I have average prices for some countries, whereby the countries for which there is an average are colored differently (depending on the level of the average), all other countries are colored gray by default.

My code for this looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(rworldmap)

## Get the world map: ##
worldMap <- getMap()

## Define vector with all european states: ##
v.europe <- c("Norway", "Sweden", "Finland", "Denmark", "United Kingdom","Ireland", "Greece",
              "Belgium", "Netherlands", "France", "Spain", "Portugal", "Luxembourg", "Croatia",
              "Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria", "Slovenia", "Italy", "Bulgaria", "Romania",
              "Czech Rep.", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Poland", "Bosnia Hercegovina", "Serbia",
              "Turkey", "Ukraine", "Moldova",  "Belarus", "Estonia", "Latvia", "Lithuania",
              "Montenegro", "Albania", "Macedonia")
              
## Select only the index of statesin europe: ##
indEU <- which(worldMap$NAME%in%v.europe)


## Extract longitude and latitude border's coordinates of states: ##
df.europeCoords <- lapply(indEU, function(i){
    df <- data.frame(worldMap@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
    df$region = as.character(worldMap$NAME[i])
    colnames(df) <- list("long", "lat", "region")
    return(df)
})
df.europeCoords <- do.call("rbind", df.europeCoords)

## Mean values of some of the states in europe: ##
meanGermany <- 33.33
meanAustria <- 35.71
meanNetherlands <- 35.9
meanBelgium <- 34.66
meanFrance <- 34.89
meanItaly <- 43.97
meanHungary <- 43.96
meanCroatia <- 42.54
meanBulgaria <- 54.61
meanGreece <- 25.72
meanNorway <- 27.64
meanSweden <- 36.41
meanFinland <- 32.13
meanDenmark <- 36.83
meanSlovakia <- 35.94
meanCzechia <- 44.15
meanRomania <- 36.52
meanSwitzerland <- 44.12
meanSerbia <- 45.53
meanSlovenia <- 45.1

## Create vector with mean values: ##
v.meanValues <- c('Germany' = meanGermany, 'Austria' = meanAustria, 'Netherlands' = meanNetherlands,
                  'Belgium' = meanBelgium, 'France' = meanFrance, 'Italy' = meanItaly, 'Greece' = meanGreece,
                  'Hungary' = meanHungary, 'Croatia' = meanCroatia, 'Bulgaria' = meanBulgaria,
                  'Norway' = meanNorway, 'Sweden' = meanSweden, 'Finland' = meanFinland, 'Denmark' = meanDenmark,
                  'Slovakia' = meanSlovakia, 'Czech Rep.' = meanCzechia, 'Romania' = meanRomania,  
                  'Serbia' = meanSerbia, 'Slovenia' = meanSlovenia, 'Switzerland' = meanSwitzerland)

## Merge mean values with european countries: ##
df.europeCoords$meanValues <- v.meanValues[match(df.europeCoords$region, names(v.meanValues))]


ax <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE
)   
## Plot the map: ##
p <- ggplot() + 
     geom_polygon(data = df.europeCoords, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = region, fill = meanValues,
                                              text = paste("<b>", region, '</b>\n',
                                                           "Price Mean: ", meanValues, "\u20ac")),
                  color = "black", size = 0.1) +
     coord_map(xlim = c(-13, 35),  ylim = c(32, 71)) +
     theme_classic() +
     scale_fill_gradient(name = "Price Mean Values", low = "#81C07A", high = "#007d3c", na.value = "#CCCCCC") +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
           axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
           axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
           axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
           axis.title = element_blank(), 
           legend.position = "none",
           plot.margin = unit(0 * c(-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5), "lines"),
     )
EuropePlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
              layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

I want to place the available mean values (as a number) in the middle of the respective country. How can I do this?

Comment: regarding the axes, maybe `+ theme_void()` does what you want, and for the colors ColorBrewer https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/38-rcolorbrewers-palettes.html might be interesting.

Comment: @D.J I have already tried ```theme_void()``` and this didn't work!

Comment: You can remove the axes using layout(). See [here](https://plotly.com/r/axes/).

Comment: @stefan thanks! With this, the y and y axis is removed completely! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions that works for me:

**Solution 1:**

I have created an Excel file with the regions and longitudes and latitudes of each country and tried to solve it as follows:

```
## Read Excel-file with longitude and latitude of each country: ##
df.longLat <- read_excel("C:/Users/z_kordasch/Documents/fire/server/input_Data/EUROPE_LongitudeLatitude.xlsx", na = "NA")

## Merge mean values to this new data frame: ##
df.longLat$meanValues <- v.meanValues[match(df.longLat$region, names(v.meanValues))]
as.data.frame(df.longLat)

## Add it to plot: ##
p <- p + geom_text(data = df.longLat, aes(long, lat, label = meanValues), size = 2)
EuropePlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
              layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)
```

**Solution 2:**

I calculated the mean values of the longitudes and latitudes of each country with the following code:

```
df.europeCoords <- aggregate(cbind(long, lat) ~ region, data = df.europeCoords, 
                             FUN = function(x)mean(range(x)))

df.europeCoords$meanValues <- v.meanValues[match(df.europeCoords$region, names(v.meanValues))]

p <- p + geom_text(data = df.europeCoords, aes(long, lat, label = meanValues), size = 2)
EuropePlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
              layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)
```